# Issue in creating Jmeter - Java Sampler

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0

I have created a Java request sampler using `Jmeter 4.0`. After packaging the jar using maven, I copied the jar file to lib/ext and I can see the class in java request. But, when I try to execute, I'm getting the below error. Can someone help me to understand what went wrong?

```
2020-06-19 12:38:01,265 WARN o.j.r.PluginManagerMenuItem: Failed to load plugin updates info
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
```

Also this is the way I have created the Java request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting is related to [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/) not being able to connect to the [JMeter Plugins Repository](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginRepositoryDescriptorFormat) due to some problem with SSL certificates.

If you're behind a corporate proxy - you need to [make JMeter aware of this proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server).